# How to detect the change of a select tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to detect the change of the **select** tag. My goal is to reset or change a value if the ** options** of the **select** tag is changed. Please have a look at the image below.

[image]

In this image, the Burger option is selected, and the price is set to $4.99 for 1 piece. If I increase the quantity by 1, then the price will be $9.88.
If I select another option such as "Chicken Fry or French Fry," the quantity will reset to 1, and this is what I am seeking help for.

My codes

```js
const amountEl = document.getElementById('amount');
const addEl = document.getElementById('add');
const deleteEl = document.getElementById('delete');
const totalPriceEl = document.getElementById('total-price');

function totalPriceCount(value) {
  const selectEl = document.getElementById('select');
  const selectValue = parseInt(selectEl.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
  let totalPrice = 0;

  switch (selectValue) {
    case 1:
      totalPrice = 3.99 * value;
      break;
    case 2:
      totalPrice = 4.99 * value;
      break;
    case 3:
      totalPrice = 1.99 * value;
      break;
    case 4:
      totalPrice = 1.29 * value;
      break;
    default:
      totalPrice = 1.49 * value;
      break;
  }

  totalPriceEl.innerText = totalPrice;
}

function increaseAmount() {
  let value = parseInt(amountEl.innerText);
  value += 1;
  amountEl.innerText = value;
  totalPriceCount(value);
}

function decreaseAmount() {
  let value = parseInt(amountEl.innerText);
  value -= 1;
  if (value < 1) {
    alert('Food item can not be 0');
  } else {
    amountEl.innerText = value;
  }
  totalPriceCount(value);
}

addEl.addEventListener('click', increaseAmount);
deleteEl.addEventListener('click', decreaseAmount);
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #fff;
  --secondary-color: #000;
  --nav: rgb(90, 115, 184);
}

body {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

nav {
  background: var(--nav);
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.dark-mode {
  --primary-color: #000;
  --secondary-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

#form {
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: auto;
}

i:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#table {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
  max-width: 768px;
}

#hero-text {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon"
    href="https://res.cloudinary.com/djz3p8sux/image/upload/v1629822917/image/general-purpose-favicon-dabananda-mitra_zuuv1x.png"
    type="image/x-icon" />
  <!-- FontAwesome Icon -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- Boostrap Icon -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Order Food -->
  <section class="order container py-5" id="order">
    <h2 class="text-center mb-5">Order Your Desire Food</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-3">
        <select class="form-select form-select-lg w-50" id="select">
              <option selected disabled>Chose Your Happiness</option>
              <option value="1" id="one">Chicken Fry</option>
              <option value="2" id="two">Burger</option>
              <option value="3" id="three">French Fry</option>
          </select>
        <div class="ms-2 item-amount">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="add">
                  <i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i>
              </button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary px-4" id="amount">1</button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" id="delete">
                  <i class="bi bi-dash-lg"></i>
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary px-5 me-2 total-price">$<span id="total-price">00.00</span></button>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success">Place Order</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Food Prices -->
  <section class="food-price container py-5">
    <div class="title-box text-center py-5">
      <h2>Price List</h2>
      <p class="text-muted fst-italic">(All VAT+SD+SC included)</p>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped mx-auto" id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Item Code</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">101</th>
          <td>Chicken Fry</td>
          <td>$3.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">102</th>
          <td>Burger</td>
          <td>$4.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">103</th>
          <td>French Fry</td>
          <td>$1.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">104</th>
          <td>Cold Drinks</td>
          <td>$1.29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">105</th>
          <td>Coffee</td>
          <td>$1.49</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I detect the change of select tag options?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML:
Add a `onchange` attribute to your select element.

```
<select class="form-select form-select-lg w-50" id="select" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option selected disabled>Chose Your Happiness</option>
      <option value="1" id="one">Chicken Fry</option>
      <option value="2" id="two">Burger</option>
      <option value="3" id="three">French Fry</option>
 </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    amount.innerText = 1;
}
```

Comment: @SatyajitRoy This is a very poor suggestion. You already have eventListeners for the increase and decrease. You just needed one for the select

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

I strongly recommend to NOT use inline onchange or similar.

You already have eventListeners on the increase and decrease, so just add the same to the select and simplify the code in the increase and decrease

```
const food = document.getElementById('select');
let numberOfItems = 1;
food.addEventListener('change', totalPriceCount);
```

And add it to the increase and decrease too:

```
function increaseAmount() {
  numberOfItems++
  totalPriceCount();
}


function decreaseAmount() {
  numberOfItems--
  if (numberOfItems <= 0) {
    numberOfItems = 1;
    alert('Food item can not be 0');
  }  
  totalPriceCount();
}
```

Then with a small change, any click or change will calculate

```
function totalPriceCount() {
  const selectValue = parseInt(food.value); // can be NaN if you do not choose
  let totalPrice = 0;
  switch (selectValue) {
    case 1:
      totalPrice = 3.99 * amount;
      break;
```

Note: You might want to tell the user they MUST get at least a coffee if they do not order a burger

The initial amount is the price of a coffee

```js
const amountEl = document.getElementById('amount');
const addEl = document.getElementById('add');
const deleteEl = document.getElementById('delete');
const totalPriceEl = document.getElementById('total-price');
const food = document.getElementById('select');
let numberOfItems = 1;

food.addEventListener("change",totalPriceCount)

function totalPriceCount() {
  const selectValue = parseInt(food.value);
  let totalPrice = 0;
  switch (selectValue) {
    case 1:
      totalPrice = 3.99 * numberOfItems;
      break;
    case 2:
      totalPrice = 4.99 * numberOfItems;
      break;
    case 3:
      totalPrice = 1.99 * numberOfItems;
      break;
    case 4:
      totalPrice = 1.29 * numberOfItems;
      break;
    default:
      totalPrice = 1.49 * numberOfItems;
      break;
  }
  amountEl.innerText = numberOfItems;
  totalPriceEl.innerText = totalPrice.toFixed(2);
}

function increaseAmount() {
  numberOfItems++
  totalPriceCount();
}

function decreaseAmount() {
  numberOfItems--
  if (numberOfItems <= 0) {
    numberOfItems = 1;
    alert('Food item can not be 0');
  }  
  totalPriceCount();
}


addEl.addEventListener('click', increaseAmount);
deleteEl.addEventListener('click', decreaseAmount);
totalPriceCount(); // initialise
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #fff;
  --secondary-color: #000;
  --nav: rgb(90, 115, 184);
}

body {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

nav {
  background: var(--nav);
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.dark-mode {
  --primary-color: #000;
  --secondary-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

#form {
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: auto;
}

i:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#table {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
  max-width: 768px;
}

#hero-text {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon"
    href="https://res.cloudinary.com/djz3p8sux/image/upload/v1629822917/image/general-purpose-favicon-dabananda-mitra_zuuv1x.png"
    type="image/x-icon" />
  <!-- FontAwesome Icon -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- Boostrap Icon -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Order Food -->
  <section class="order container py-5" id="order">
    <h2 class="text-center mb-5">Order Your Desire Food</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-3">
        <select class="form-select form-select-lg w-50" id="select">
              <option selected disabled value="0">Chose Your Happiness</option>
              <option value="1" id="one">Chicken Fry</option>
              <option value="2" id="two">Burger</option>
              <option value="3" id="three">French Fry</option>
          </select>
        <div class="ms-2 item-amount">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="add">
                  <i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i>
              </button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary px-4" id="amount">1</button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" id="delete">
                  <i class="bi bi-dash-lg"></i>
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary px-5 me-2 total-price">$<span id="total-price">00.00</span></button>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success">Place Order</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Food Prices -->
  <section class="food-price container py-5">
    <div class="title-box text-center py-5">
      <h2>Price List</h2>
      <p class="text-muted fst-italic">(All VAT+SD+SC included)</p>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped mx-auto" id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Item Code</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">101</th>
          <td>Chicken Fry</td>
          <td>$3.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">102</th>
          <td>Burger</td>
          <td>$4.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">103</th>
          <td>French Fry</td>
          <td>$1.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">104</th>
          <td>Cold Drinks</td>
          <td>$1.29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">105</th>
          <td>Coffee</td>
          <td>$1.49</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not really though, when you change the item quantity it doesn't change, and when you change items the price does not go back to a single quantity price.

Comment: it doesn't really matter though

Comment: @TomTomTom You are correct, I missed showing the number of items. I also corrected the amount with a toFixed now

Answer (score -1):

I would try something like this. You can attach a `change` event listener to the `selectEl` which will fire every time the select box changes. And to that listener you can just reset the count to 1, and re-calculate the value for 1 item.

```js
const amountEl = document.getElementById('amount');
const addEl = document.getElementById('add');
const deleteEl = document.getElementById('delete');
const totalPriceEl = document.getElementById('total-price');
const selectEl = document.getElementById('select'); // moved this out of the function so it can be used at the bottom

function totalPriceCount(value) {
  const selectValue = parseInt(selectEl.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
  let totalPrice = 0;

  switch (selectValue) {
    case 1:
      totalPrice = 3.99 * value;
      break;
    case 2:
      totalPrice = 4.99 * value;
      break;
    case 3:
      totalPrice = 1.99 * value;
      break;
    case 4:
      totalPrice = 1.29 * value;
      break;
    default:
      totalPrice = 1.49 * value;
      break;
  }

  totalPriceEl.innerText = totalPrice;
}

function increaseAmount() {
  let value = parseInt(amountEl.innerText);
  value += 1;
  amountEl.innerText = value;
  totalPriceCount(value);
}

function decreaseAmount() {
  let value = parseInt(amountEl.innerText);
  value -= 1;
  if (value < 1) {
    alert('Food item can not be 0');
  } else {
    amountEl.innerText = value;
  }
  totalPriceCount(value);
}

function resetAmount() {
  amountEl.innerText = 1;
  totalPriceCount(1*emphasized text*);
}

addEl.addEventListener('click', increaseAmount);
deleteEl.addEventListener('click', decreaseAmount);
selectEl.addEventListener('change', resetAmount);
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #fff;
  --secondary-color: #000;
  --nav: rgb(90, 115, 184);
}

body {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

nav {
  background: var(--nav);
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.dark-mode {
  --primary-color: #000;
  --secondary-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

#form {
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: auto;
}

i:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#table {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
  max-width: 768px;
}

#hero-text {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon"
    href="https://res.cloudinary.com/djz3p8sux/image/upload/v1629822917/image/general-purpose-favicon-dabananda-mitra_zuuv1x.png"
    type="image/x-icon" />
  <!-- FontAwesome Icon -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- Boostrap Icon -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Order Food -->
  <section class="order container py-5" id="order">
    <h2 class="text-center mb-5">Order Your Desire Food</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-3">
        <select class="form-select form-select-lg w-50" id="select">
              <option selected disabled>Chose Your Happiness</option>
              <option value="1" id="one">Chicken Fry</option>
              <option value="2" id="two">Burger</option>
              <option value="3" id="three">French Fry</option>
          </select>
        <div class="ms-2 item-amount">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="add">
                  <i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i>
              </button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary px-4" id="amount">1</button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" id="delete">
                  <i class="bi bi-dash-lg"></i>
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary px-5 me-2 total-price">$<span id="total-price">00.00</span></button>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success">Place Order</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Food Prices -->
  <section class="food-price container py-5">
    <div class="title-box text-center py-5">
      <h2>Price List</h2>
      <p class="text-muted fst-italic">(All VAT+SD+SC included)</p>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped mx-auto" id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Item Code</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">101</th>
          <td>Chicken Fry</td>
          <td>$3.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">102</th>
          <td>Burger</td>
          <td>$4.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">103</th>
          <td>French Fry</td>
          <td>$1.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">104</th>
          <td>Cold Drinks</td>
          <td>$1.29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">105</th>
          <td>Coffee</td>
          <td>$1.49</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need add event to listen selected option value change. When selected option changed you can reset amount. Use JavaScript for this:

```
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
    //when selected item change reset amount to 1
    document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML = 1;
});
```

```js
const amountEl = document.getElementById('amount');
const addEl = document.getElementById('add');
const deleteEl = document.getElementById('delete');
const totalPriceEl = document.getElementById('total-price');

function totalPriceCount(value) {
  const selectEl = document.getElementById('select');
  const selectValue = parseInt(selectEl.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
  let totalPrice = 0;

  switch (selectValue) {
    case 1:
      totalPrice = 3.99 * value;
      break;
    case 2:
      totalPrice = 4.99 * value;
      break;
    case 3:
      totalPrice = 1.99 * value;
      break;
    case 4:
      totalPrice = 1.29 * value;
      break;
    default:
      totalPrice = 1.49 * value;
      break;
  }

  totalPriceEl.innerText = totalPrice;
}

function increaseAmount() {
  let value = parseInt(amountEl.innerText);
  value += 1;
  amountEl.innerText = value;
  totalPriceCount(value);
}

function decreaseAmount() {
  let value = parseInt(amountEl.innerText);
  value -= 1;
  if (value < 1) {
    alert('Food item can not be 0');
  } else {
    amountEl.innerText = value;
  }
  totalPriceCount(value);
}

addEl.addEventListener('click', increaseAmount);
deleteEl.addEventListener('click', decreaseAmount);
//TODO : add start
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML = 1;
});
//TODO : add end
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #fff;
  --secondary-color: #000;
  --nav: rgb(90, 115, 184);
}

body {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

nav {
  background: var(--nav);
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.dark-mode {
  --primary-color: #000;
  --secondary-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

#form {
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: auto;
}

i:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#table {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
  max-width: 768px;
}

#hero-text {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon"
    href="https://res.cloudinary.com/djz3p8sux/image/upload/v1629822917/image/general-purpose-favicon-dabananda-mitra_zuuv1x.png"
    type="image/x-icon" />
  <!-- FontAwesome Icon -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- Boostrap Icon -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Order Food -->
  <section class="order container py-5" id="order">
    <h2 class="text-center mb-5">Order Your Desire Food</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-3">
        <select class="form-select form-select-lg w-50" id="select">
              <option selected disabled>Chose Your Happiness</option>
              <option value="1" id="one">Chicken Fry</option>
              <option value="2" id="two">Burger</option>
              <option value="3" id="three">French Fry</option>
          </select>
        <div class="ms-2 item-amount">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="add">
                  <i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i>
              </button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary px-4" id="amount">1</button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" id="delete">
                  <i class="bi bi-dash-lg"></i>
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary px-5 me-2 total-price">$<span id="total-price">00.00</span></button>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success">Place Order</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Food Prices -->
  <section class="food-price container py-5">
    <div class="title-box text-center py-5">
      <h2>Price List</h2>
      <p class="text-muted fst-italic">(All VAT+SD+SC included)</p>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped mx-auto" id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Item Code</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">101</th>
          <td>Chicken Fry</td>
          <td>$3.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">102</th>
          <td>Burger</td>
          <td>$4.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">103</th>
          <td>French Fry</td>
          <td>$1.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">104</th>
          <td>Cold Drinks</td>
          <td>$1.29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">105</th>
          <td>Coffee</td>
          <td>$1.49</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer provides no explanation on what the code does. Could you add an explanation for each code snippet you provided?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Community I'm sorry about my answer unclear.I was modified answer.i will pay attention to this later.